# Finding an ordered pair

Tags: functions

Define
$F : ℤ ✕ ℤ → ℤ ✕ ℤ
  $ as follows: For every ordered pair
$(a, b)$
of integers,
$F(a, b) = (2a + 1, 3b − 2).$

Find $F(7,7)$

Can someone walk me through this step by step?

Comment: Substitute $a=7$ and $b=7$ into the equation given.

Comment: Is that all? Got confused with the Z✕Z

Comment: @ScottAdamson The ZxZ just mean that you have pairs of integers, i.e. $a$ and $b$ are integers, and also the image of the function.

Comment: @ScottAdamson yep, that's all. It's easy to overthink things once you get to the higher levels.

Answer (score 2):

We may directly substitute:

$F(7,7) = (2(7)+1,3(7)-2) = \boxed{(15, 19).}$